# How to override a function in .NET 4.7.2 C# 7.3

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a function overridable but I keep getting:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS8703  The modifier 'virtual' is not valid for this item in C#
> 7.3. Please use language version '8.0' or greater.

```
public interface IFruit
{

    protected virtual void Eat(IFork connectionModuleData);

}

public interface IApple:IFruit
{

    protected Override void Eat(IAppleFork connectionModuleData);

}
```

Comment: Interfaces in C# earlier than v8 don't allow for access modifiers - just remove `protected virtual` and `protected override` entirely. (And the `IApple` method wouldn't *override* the `IFruit` method anyway...)

Comment: You can not enable C# version 8.0 for .NET Framework v4.7.2 beacuse [it is supported only on .NET Core 3.x and newer versions.](https://learn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version)

Comment: Even if what you wanted was syntactically possible (which would be the case if you used classes rather than interfaces), be aware that it would still not be allowed semantically. Because every `IFruit` must be eatable with an `IFork`, you cannot specify that `IApple` (which is an `IFruit`) may only be eaten with an `IAppleFork`, because people must be able to treat it as an `IFruit`. You may only make your parameters *less* derived, not *more*.

Answer (score 1):

How about use generics instead?

```cs
public interface IFruit<TTool>
   where TTool:IFork
{
    void Eat(TTool connectionModuleData);
}

public interface IApple:IFruit<IAppleFork> // assuming IAppleFork is IFork
{
}
```